# Synchronous sleep into asyncio coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a coroutine as follows:

```
async def download():
    downloader = DataManager()
    downloader.download()
```

`DataManager.download()` method looks like:

```
def download(self):
    start_multiple_docker_containers()
    while True:
        check_containers_statuses()
        sleep(N)  # synchronous sleep from time module
```

Is this a good practice? If no, how can I use `asyncio.sleep` in `download()`?

Or maybe such code structure is conceptually wrong?

Comment: Can you make `DataManager.download` a coroutine?

Comment: Yes, of course. But, if I want to break up the code on different methods, have to make them as coroutines too. I'm afraid it will adversely affect the performance, if download tasks will be too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
import asyncio
import time


# Mocks of domain-specific functions
# ----------------------------------

def get_container_status(container_id, initial_time):
    """This mocks container status to change to 'exited' in 10 seconds"""
    if time.time() - initial_time < 10:
        print("%s: container %s still running" % (time.time(), container_id))
        return 'running'
    else:
        print("%s: container %s exited" % (time.time(), container_id))
        return 'exited'

def is_download_complete(container_id, initial_time):
    """This mocks download finished in 20 seconds after program's start"""
    if time.time() - initial_time < 20:
        print("%s: download from %s in progress" % (time.time(), container_id))
        return False
    else:
        print("%s: download from %s done" % (time.time(), container_id))
        return True

def get_downloaded_data(container_id):
    return "foo"


# Coroutines
# ----------

async def container_exited(container_id, initial_time):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # == setTimeout(1000), != sleep(1000)
        if get_container_status(container_id, initial_time) == 'exited':
            return container_id

async def download_data_by_container_id(container_id, initial_time):
    container_id = await container_exited(container_id, initial_time)
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if is_download_complete(container_id, initial_time):
            return get_downloaded_data(container_id)


# Main loop
# ---------

if __name__ == "__main__":

    initial_time = time.time()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(download_data_by_container_id("A", initial_time)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(download_data_by_container_id("B", initial_time))
    ]

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

    loop.close()
```

Results in:

```
1487334722.321165: container A still running
1487334722.321412: container B still running
1487334723.325897: container A still running
1487334723.3259578: container B still running
1487334724.3285959: container A still running
1487334724.328662: container B still running
1487334725.3312798: container A still running
1487334725.331337: container B still running
1487334726.3340318: container A still running
1487334726.33409: container B still running
1487334727.336779: container A still running
1487334727.336842: container B still running
1487334728.339425: container A still running
1487334728.339506: container B still running
1487334729.34211: container A still running
1487334729.342168: container B still running
1487334730.3448708: container A still running
1487334730.34493: container B still running
1487334731.34754: container A exited
1487334731.347598: container B exited
1487334732.350253: download from A in progress
1487334732.3503108: download from B in progress
1487334733.354369: download from A in progress
1487334733.354424: download from B in progress
1487334734.354686: download from A in progress
1487334734.3548028: download from B in progress
1487334735.358371: download from A in progress
1487334735.358461: download from B in progress
1487334736.3610592: download from A in progress
1487334736.361115: download from B in progress
1487334737.363115: download from A in progress
1487334737.363211: download from B in progress
1487334738.3664992: download from A in progress
1487334738.36656: download from B in progress
1487334739.369131: download from A in progress
1487334739.36919: download from B in progress
1487334740.371079: download from A in progress
1487334740.37119: download from B in progress
1487334741.374521: download from A done
1487334741.3745651: download from B done
```

As for the `sleep()` function - no, you shouldn't use it. It blocks the whole python interpreter for 1 second, which is not what you want.

Remember, you don't have *parallelism* (threads etc.), you have *concurrency*.

I.e. you have a python interpreter with just 1 thread of execution, where your main loop and all your coroutines run, preempting each other. You want your interpreter to spend 99.999% of its working time in that main loop, created by asyncio, polling sockets and waiting for timeouts.

All your coroutines should return as fast as possible and definitely shouldn't contain blocking `sleep` - if you call it, it blocks the whole interpreter and prevents main loop from getting information from sockets or running coroutines in response to data, arriving to those sockets.

So, instead you should await `asyncio.sleep()` which is essentially equivalent to Javascript's `setTimeout()` - it just tells the main loop that in certain time it should wake this coroutine up and continue running it.

---

Suggested reading:

- https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely a bad practice, as time.sleep() will block everything, while you only want to block the specific coroutine (i guess).

you are making a sync operation in async world.

What about the following pattern?

```
async def download():
    downloader = DataManager()
    downloader.start_multiple_docker_containers()
    while True:
        downloader.check_containers_statuses()
        await syncio.sleep(N)
```

Comment: It's working fine. Don't know why, but in the last evening, code like:

async def some1():
  await some2();   

async def some2():
   await someN()

seemed unpretty.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at asyncio, but it seems that if you run sync code like this

`f =  app.loop.run_in_executor(None, your_sync_function, app,param1,param2,...)`

then `your_sync_function` is running in a separate thread, and you can do `time.sleep()` without disturbing the asyncio loop. It blocks the loop executor's thread, but not the asyncio thread. At least, this is what it seems to do.

If you want to send messages from `your_sync_function` back to asyncio's loop, look into the `janus` library

More tips on this:

https://carlosmaniero.github.io/asyncio-handle-blocking-functions.html